# Using "find" to list only directories with no more childs

Tags: linux, command-line

How can only directories be listed, that do not have another child directory?

Imagine a structure like `/A /A/AA /A/AB /A/AB/ABB /B /C /C/CC /C/CC/CCC /C/CC/CCC/CCCC` I would like to use `find` to list only `/A/AA /A/AB/ABB /B /C/CC/CCC/CCCC`.

The starting point would be `find . -type d`, but neither `-mindepth` nor `-maxdepth` can be used, can `-noleaf` help (I could not get it to  react the way I wanted it to)?

Comment: Same question on Stack Overflow: [Use GNU find to show only the leaf directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269798/use-gnu-find-to-show-only-the-leaf-directories)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a POSIX-compliant solution that postprocesses the output of `find` to remove directories that have a listed subdirectory. It assumes that there are no newlines in the directory names.

```
{ find . -type d; echo; } |
awk 'index($0,prev"/")!=1 && NR!=1 {print prev}
     1 {sub(/\/$/,""); prev=$0}'
```

Explanation: the awk script delays the printing of each line until it's read the next line and only prints the previous line if it's not a prefix. This takes advantage of the fact that `find` lists subdirectories immediately after their parent. The extra `"/"` is to avoid spuriously removing `foo` when `foobar` also exists. The inelegant `NR!=1` avoids printing an initial empty line, and the inelegant `echo;` is not to have an equally inelegant special case for the last line. The call to `sub` removes a trailing slash from the toplevel directory, in case e.g. `find ./` was called.

---

As usual there's a cryptic zsh one-liner.

```
echo **/.(e\''test -z $REPLY/*(/DN[1])'\':h)
```

Longer, more readable version:

```
is_leaf () { [ -z $REPLY/*(/DN[1]) ] }
echo **/.(+is_leaf:h)
```

The last line can be simplified to `echo **/(+is_leaf)` if you dont' mind the trailing `/`.

Summary explanation: The stuff in parentheses are *glob qualifiers*, documented in the `zshexpn` man page. We filter the results of the glob `**/` (expanding to the current directory and all its subdirectories), keeping only those for which the function `is_leaf` (or the code between `'…'`) returns 0. The filter code globs the subdirectories of the match being tested (`$REPLY`) (in fact, `[1]` makes it stops after the first subdirectory) and returns a status indicating whether at least one subdirectory was found. The glob qualifier `/` restricts the expansion to directories; `N` means the expansion is empty if there is no match; `D` causes dot files to be included; `:h` is a history modifier and causes the `/.` suffix to be stripped (in general it means `dirname`).

Just to illustrate the possibilities of zsh's glob qualifiers, here are two other variants (longer and I think more obscure) with a corresponding `is_leaf` function:

```
echo **/.(e\''tmp=($REPLY/*(/DN[1])); ((!#tmp))'\':h)
echo **/.(e\''$REPLY/*(/DN[1]e:REPLY=false:)'\':h)
is_leaf () { set -- $REPLY/*(/DN[1]); ((!#)); }
is_leaf () { return $REPLY/*(/DN[1]e:REPLY=1:) }
```

Comment: It looks like I should start working with zsh... Anyway, I think the awk script more readable than the sed script. But the whole find/awk breaks, if a path different from "." is specified for find. In this case, the path name would be repeated as a first output if there exist any leafes below that path. Example: `mkdir -p A/AA; { find A/ -type d; echo; } | awk 'index($0,prev"/")!=1 && NR!=1 {print prev} 1 {prev=$0}'` will output `A/` as well as `A/AA`. I could not test the zsh yet...

Comment: @MaoPU: the problem in your example is the trailing `/`; the code would have worked with `find A` or `find /A`. I've fixed my answer. There's still a very uncommon edge case that's not right (if you run the code in a filesystem with no directory other than the root, you get an empty line instead of a line with `/`). Change the awk `print` statement accordingly if you care about this bug. I've also found a slightly simpler zsh version (it's almost readable now).

Comment: Great explanation. I found out, that bash-4.x also supports `**` globbing, so there might be a way to write one of those neat one liners in bash, too. Since the original question suggested the usage of `find` and the `awk` script is fairly readable, I went basically for this solution and added `leaf () { { find -- "${1:-.}" -type d; echo; } |    awk 'index($0,prev"/")!=1 && NR!=1 {print prev} 1 {sub(/\/$/,""); prev=$0}'; }` to my `.bashrc`. Thank you.

Comment: @MaoPU: bash 4 has `**`, so you don't need `find`, but you still need some other way of filtering out the non-leaf directories. You can use a `for` loop over `**/.`, but it's not really one-liner material.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use:

```
leaf () { find "${1:-.}" -depth -type d | sed  'h; :b; $b; N; /^\(.*\)\/.*\n\1$/ { g; bb }; $ {x; b}; P; D'; }
```

Call it using the directory to start from:

```
leaf /start/dir
```

Comment: I couldn't not upvote a sed script that uses the other operators (than `s`), especially since the hold space is particularly appropriate here. (Note that the semicolon isn't POSIX and may have to be replaced by newlines outside Linux.) But I couldn't upvote an unquoted variable substitution! (And there's still the problem of an argument whose name begins with `-`, which is a general `find` annoyance.)

Comment: @Gilles: What is the problem of other operators than `s` (just joking, right?) Just to understand this: What is the problem of an unquoted variable substitution? None of my test cases broke the script. Anyway, is there a solution for the names starting with `-` (don't see a general `find` solution to this in your answer neither)?

Comment: @MaoPU: For names starting with `-` (such as a directory called `-print`), I think if you have a single path and believe in the implementer scrupulously following a 21st-century version of POSIX, then `find -- "${1:-.}"` is good enough. Otherwise you can preprocess the argument to prepend `./` if it starts with `-`.

Comment: @MaoPU: For why the quotes are needed, try with a directory called `*` (without quotes, the shell would expand the pattern) or `foo bar` (without quotes, the shell would split the argument into words).

Comment: @Gilles: Yes, in general in know this, but in this case I could not reproduce an error with a path containting white space. Also I was trying to experiment with the `find --` to stop it from reading arguments, but it would not work. I think, to make it bullet proof, you need to test for relative or absolute paths and prepend a `./` in case it is a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

To find directories that have no subdirectories:

`find dir -type d -links 2`

explanation: a directory has a link for each subdirectory in it, a link from its parent and a link to itself, thus a count of 2 links if it has no subdirectories.